# How to filter according to child's child field in Tastypie?

Tags: django, tastypie

I have a model like:

```
Shop
    Categories
         Items
```

I can filter categories of a shop like this:

```
categories = fields.ToManyField('api.CategoryResource', attribute=lambda bundle: Category.objects.filter(parent__isnull=True), full= True)
```

Let's say I want to filter published items when I query for a shop.

How can I filter that? Where should I write the query?

```
    items = fields.ToManyField(ItemResource, attribute=lambda bundle: Item.objects.filter(category=bundle.obj, published=True),related_name='items', full=True)
```

this code gives me error:

```
{"error": "The model '<Category: category1>' has an empty attribute '<function <lambda> at 0x10ba506e0>' and doesn't allow a null value."}
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this error occurs when the list returned by the lambda function is empty.
So adding null=True will fix this.

So you end up with this:

```
    items = fields.ToManyField(ItemResource, attribute=lambda bundle: Item.objects.filter(category=bundle.obj, published=True),related_name='items', full=True, null=True)
```